# System.Data.SQLite Windows x64 install fails; could not load file or assembly or dependency error

Tags: windows-7-x64, system.data.sqlite, failed-installation

I downloaded the 64-bit Windows SQLite setup executable to install on my Windows 7 x64 machine:

```
       sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x64-2010-1.0.78.0.exe 
      (11.60 MiB)
```

and ran the setup. It failed with this error:

```
      Could not open 
      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NET Framework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx
```

There was no "AssemblyFoldersEx" key beneath "v4.0.30319". So I created the key there and re-ran the setup, which completed this time without error.

However, when I try to add the reference, System.Data.SQLite does not appear in the list of components on the .NET tab.

What would be the next troubleshooting step?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since `VS2010` is `Win32` and not `x64`, you need to install the `Win32` setup to get design-time support. You can still use the `x64` binaries with your application, the `Win32` is only needed for **VS integration**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to install Win32 SQLite for design time support; after download and executed 32bit setup (sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-x-x.x.x.x.exe), if you still facing the same error you can run the VS designer components 32bit installer without the option checked by following steps:

1. Open a Visual Studio command prompt.
2. Change to the "System.Data.SQLite\2010\bin" install directory.

   ```
   eg: CD D:\Programs\System.Data.SQLite\2010\x86\bin\
   ```
3. Run the following commands:

   ```
   corflags /32BIT+ /Force Installer.exe
   sn -k System.Data.SQLite.snk
   sn -Ra Installer.exe System.Data.SQLite.snk
   Installer.exe -install true -installFlags AllExceptGAC -tracePriority Lowest -verbose true -noCompact true -noNetFx20 true -noVs2008 true -whatIf false -confirm true
   ```

Command explaination:

- **corflags /32BIT+ /Force Installer.exe**
  Using the "corflags" tool (part of the .NET SDK), flag the "Installer.exe" tool as 32-bit only
- **sn -k System.Data.SQLite.snk**
  Generate any strong name key pair (Any key pair SNK file will work here)
- **sn -Ra Installer.exe System.Data.SQLite.snk**
  Re-sign the "Installer.exe" assembly using the above generated strong name key pair
- **Installer.exe -install true -installFlags All... -confirm true**
  Run installer with neccessary flags, but the most important is to put in '-confirm true'; as this is the needed flag for SQLite installer which prevent user execute setup by clicking the installer.exe directly in windows explorer.

Comment: OMG, why such torture!? Dare I ask how to get VS 2017 or 2013 integration working?